# Angular js adding empty option in dropdown?

Tags: html, angularjs

Angular js is adding empty option in dropdown.
**I am not using ng-options**
Just a plain ng-model

```
<select ng-model="newOpportunity.meetingStatusId" style="width: 127px;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
        <option value="10">Business Initiate</option>
        <option value="9">Business Reported</option>
        <option value="1">Business Reject</option>

</select>
```

When i am exploring Dom option In Intenet Explorer it is showing

```
<select style="width: 127px;" ng-model="newOpportunity.meetingStatusId"> 
     <option value="? number:9 ?"></option>
    <option selected="selected" value="?">Select</option>
    <option value="10">Business Initiate</option>
   <option value="9">Business Reported</option>
    <option value="1">Business Reject</option>
 </select>
```

How to get rid of these blank option without using ng-options? I am stuck around this problems since 4 days!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise your model object as bellow.

```
$scope.newOpportunity={
    'meetingStatusId' : ""
    };
```